# Hibernate transaction issue

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-aop

I have a following setup. I'm using spring data for accessing data via hibernate

```
public class Controller {

private ServiceA serviceA
public A someMethod () {
   A a = new A();
   .
   .
   .
   a=serviceA.add(a);
   .
   .
   return a;
 }
}

public class ServiceAImpl implements ServiceA {

public RepoA repoA

@Transcational 
@AnnotationUsedInAroundAspect(name="xyz")
public A add(A a) {
   A existingA = repoA.get(a.id);
   repoA.delete(existingA);
   return repoA.Save(a);

  }
}

public class Aspect {

   @Around("@annotation(a)")
   public Object AroundAspect(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, AnnotationUsedInAroundAspect a) {
  Object value = joinPoint.proceed();
  /**
  Not all statements are flushed to db at this point
  */
  .
  .
  .
  return value;

}


}
```

At the Aspect(around the commented section), the delete is flushed to the DB but the save(saving the new A object) has not yet. But if delete statement is removed, then save is flushed to the db at that point. Only the first statement on a given table is flushed and the rest is not at this point. But once the control is back to the controller all statements are flushed. Can some help me understand what is happening or if there is an issue with hibernate ?

Comment: You're confusing flushed and committed. The commit happens when the transaction is committed. And this commit automatically calls flush(). If you want everything to be flushed at some arbitrary time, then call flush() explicitely. Otherwise, Hibernate waits as much as possible, i.e. until the commit.

Comment: if thats the case then Y is delete flushed to the db ?

Comment: Hibernate must flush before some other operations are done, to make sure everything works as if every operation did effectively write to the database.

Comment: y doesn't it flush both the statements (delete and save) at the same time. Y does it flush only the delete ??(note: save is also flushed but only at a later point)

Comment: Because the delete must be flushed for the save to work fine, and the save can wait until transaction commit time because it's not needed before.

Comment: Is this documented in hibernate ? Accepting what is said above, y does hibernate wait since the control is out of the transaction method(block)

Comment: It doesn't wait until it's out of transaction. It waits until just before the commit of the transaction. The goal is to make as few roadtrips to the database to make things faster.

Comment: Also its not just delete, if delete is replaced with another SAVE statement(but on the same table) , only the first save statement is flushed  and the subsequent statements are flush only later

Comment: When does commit of the transaction happen, when its out of the method that is annotated with @Transactional right ?, In that case, when the control is in the aspect after proceed is executed , all the statements must be flushed, but that not the case

Comment: Spring also uses aspects to deal with transactional methods. So the Spring transactional aspect wraps your aspect, which wraps the method call. And the transactional aspect is the one which commits the transaction.

Comment: But then how does the first statement gets flushed immediately ? when all the other statements (any no of statement but on the same table) flushed by the transactional aspect ?

Comment: A transaction is committed exactly once. Between the start and the commit of the transaction, SQL statements modifying the database can be executed many times. Hibernate executes these statements everytime it flushes. It can flush several times during the transaction, and you can explicitely ask it to flush by calling the method flush(). flushing consists in writing all the changes that are kept in memoty to the database. That must be done, at the very least, before the commit. But it can also happen, several times, before the commit.

Comment: but then, during the time gap between flushing and commit, if db is queried, the result must be the old data right ? which is not the case. I get the new data based on the the first statement that is flushed. How is this possible ? and what is the logic/reason behind hibernate flushing the first statement and not the subsequent statements (related to the same table) immediately ?